# Perl how to see all fields

Tags: perl

I was looking at some code which looks like the following --

```
foreach my $name (@places{$${newones}}) {
  my $item = $$name{item};
  my $temp = $$name{temp};
}
```

I wanted to know which other fields are there like $$name{temp}, $$name{item}, how can I print all of that?

Comment: `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper $name`. And the main variable is probably `print Dumper \%places`, although it is hard to understand why someone would put an array sigil on a hash key ending.

Comment: @TLP: Maybe they tried to use a hash slice, `@hash{@keys}` returns a list of the values associated to `@keys`. But here we only have a single key...

Comment: @choroba The scalar dereference `$$` makes me think it is code written by beginners. So that is probably most likely. Also they seem to think it will be a list of values to loop over, since they put it in a for loop.

Comment: yeah, this code is ...problematic

Comment: (Removed the `operating-system` tag. Really not sure why it was there.)

Answer (score 1):

To print the other keys and values of the hashref `$name` you can do something like:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $place = "place";
my $newones = \$place;
my %names = (item => "item_value", temp => "temp_value");
my %places = (place => \%names);
for my $name (@places{$${newones}}) {
    for my $key (keys %$name) {
        say "$key = $$name{$key}";
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
temp = temp_value
item = item_value
```